# If A=0, B=1, and x=0 what are A' and B' in the logic circuit below?

Tags: digital-logic

The following circuit diagram what are A' and B'?

[image: Circuit, truth table, and Finite State Machine]

The question in the slide asks what happens if A=0, B=1, and x=0.
I understand what it means when x=0, but what exactly does this mean when A=0 and B=1? 
The way A and B are labeled in the diagram it appears like they represent the hardware device, not an input.  Can someone explain to me what A and B are exactly?

In the following diagram we are given the answer if A=0,B=1,and x=0 in red. 
Can somebody explain how they arrived at this answer?

Trying to make sense if it myself, here is my train of thought:

Input x is fed into a NOT gate, making it x'.  x' is fed into an AND gate with Q', thus making the output (x'^Q').  Which is then fed into an OR gate with Q, giving you Q OR (x' ^ Q') = (Q OR x') AND (Q OR Q') = Q OR x'.  This is fed into both inputs of B, which doesn't make any sense to me. At this point I am lost, so I would appreciate some guidance what happens to Q OR x'?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A and B are [D latches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#D_flip-flop); on the clock edge, the value on the input is latched to the Q output.

A = 1 means that the Q output associated with the A latch is high (the complementary output is thus low).

A = 0 means that the Q output associated with the A latch is low (the complementary output is thus high).

A' is the value of A after the next clock edge.

This is a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).  A and B represent the current state.  The current state, along with the input x, determine the next state denoted by the primes on A and B.

So, for example, the input to the A latch is x so, if x = 0, on the next clock edge, 0 will be latched, i.e., the Q output of the A latch will be low; A' = 0.

Following the logic, the input to the B latch is:  \$(\bar x \cdot \bar A) + B \$

So, for x=0, A = 0, B = 0, the input to B is 1 and thus, after the next clock edge the Q output of B will be high; B' = 1.

UPDATE:  a closer look shows that the schematic does not match the state transition table.  It's obvious that the input to the A latch is x and so, A' = x according to the schematic.  However, the 5th row in the state transition table has A' = 1 when x = 0.  That's not consistent.

Comment: Hi Alfred - I understood everything you said except for the part "input to the B latch is: \$(\bar x \cdot \bar A) + B \$. Can you explain to me why you are using As and Bs instead of Q and Q' ? For example, where you wrote $\bar A$\ I expected it to be\$ bar Q $\.  Where you wrote \$B\$ I expected it to be \$Q$\.  If you could please explain to me how you exchanged the Q and Q' with A' and B I would really appreciate it.

Comment: A *is* the (current) Q output of the A latch.  B *is* the (current) Q output of the B latch.  Sorry if I didn't quite make that clear.  If it's not quite yet clear, pencil in an "A" over the Q output of the A latch and a "B" over the Q output of the B latch (and likewise for the complements) and then write the logic equations.

Comment: So when A=0,B=1,x=0, using your logic, I get (0' * 0') + 1 = (1 * 1) + 1 = 1.  But the answer for B' = 0.  Why is this?

Comment: When B=1 this means the Q output for latch B is high, does this negate your formula? I guess I'm confused what the purpose of knowing whether Q for either latch is high or low.

Comment: @user1068636, I've updated my answer to address the inconsistency between the schematic and transition table.